# Word processor or workaround that won't drop MS Word formatting in margins

Tags: libreoffice, editing, microsoft-word

I'm the admin assistant for a lawyer who has his own practice. I need to be able to help him edit his pleadings. He writes the pleadings in MS Word, and I open them in LibreOffice, edit, and save them in MS Word format. LibreOffice is almost perfect for this purpose, but unfortunately it is constantly dropping the numbering in the margins. That's the only problem that has arisen so far, but maybe there will be others. So, the questions:

1.) Does anyone know how I can get the marginal numbering from Word to stay put?

2) If not, does anyone know how I could make marginal numbering in LibreOffice?

Thanks!

Comment: P.S. Cheaper workarounds are better. It's a new practice, and so it would be hard, at this point, for us to get me a MS Office suite. Thanks!

Comment: I would ask my manager to buy a license of Word...

Comment: Have you tried WPS Office (free but closed source)? It usually has a better compatibility.

Comment: Have you tried Office Online?

Comment: if  .doc is enough, try "softmaker freeoffice" (available for linux mac and windows) the free version, imports .docx, etc but just exports .doc (no .docx).  For conversions see linux "unoconv" comand.